# Asian 2bytes fonts are not supported Error during add font files

Tags: sap-smart-forms, sapscript

I'm trying to add a Japanese font file (.ttf) via SE73, but it gave me an error :  `Asian 2bytes fonts are not supported`

I would like to know if there is a way to fix this issue ?

[image]

Comment: what is the name of function module that you are using for adding Japanese font.

Comment: Via the Transaction Code SE37-> Install True Type Font

Comment: I believe  transaction is SE73.

Comment: Yess, it's se73

Comment: also asked at SCN: https://answers.sap.com/questions/736905/asian-2bytes-fonts-are-not-supported-error-during.html

Comment: You can also add fonts by executing ABAP Program RSTXSF01.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your installed version and patches, you may have several limits for CJK and big TTF files (CJK = Chinese Japanese Korean; CJK TTF files are usually big).

The issue with the TTF files is that they need to be transferred to the printers, the original solution was to store them in each spool file (to later transfer them to the printer), so, that was an issue when the TTF is big.

There are recent solutions explained in the notes 2401871 and 2504539 (links below), to circumvent the transmission of big TTF files.

The following notes may be applied to go beyond the limits:

Upload of CJK fonts :

- allowed before note 2045724
- forbidden (limiting feature) after [note 2045724 - Preventing upload of Asian fonts](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2045724)
- allowed after [note 2224063 - Upload of TrueType fonts with Korean character](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2224063) (note: it concerns CJK, not only Korean)

TTF file size:

- limited at 5 MB (bug) before note 2401871
- limited at 10 MB (feature) with [note 2401871 - Error when uploading very large TrueType fonts](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2401871)
- unlimited (feature) via the new report RSTX_SOFTREPOFONT_MANAGER of [note 2504539 - Support for fonts from Font Repository for form printing](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2504539)